# Partial Derivative Notation: Meaning and Explanation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, partial-derivative

Can someone clarify the meaning of the notation on the left hand side of the below equation:
$$ \frac{\partial(\psi,\nabla^2\psi)}{\partial(y,x)}=\frac{1}{\text{Re}}\nabla^4\psi $$
where $\psi(x,y)$. Is it just:
$$ \frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}*\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\nabla^2\psi) $$
Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: It is the determinant of the Jacobian of $\psi$ and $\nabla^{2} \psi$ $$\frac{\partial(\psi, \nabla^{2} \psi)}{\partial(y, x)} = \partial_{y} \psi \partial_{x} \nabla^{2} \psi - \partial_{x} \psi \partial_{y} \nabla^{2} \psi$$ up to a sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mattos **does** have the sign correct- assuming the correct order for x and y in the denominator is the one given: y,x rather than x,y.

As a determinant,
$\frac{(\partial \psi, \nabla^2\psi)}{(y, x)}= \begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial \nabla^2 \psi}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \nabla^2 \psi}{\partial x}\end{vmatrix}$